# Genetic Algorithm - better crossover/mutation algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

For the basic Genetic Algorithm implementation with a random crossover boundary and random number of mutations at random bit positions, a lot of inferior children are created and leaves the optimum solution to be discovered by chance. This wastes a lot of CPU, and the user does not know when the optimum solution is found, because it could always be "the next one".

Is there an algorithm to consistently get better children rather than leave this important process to chance?

Thank you.

Comment: The best cross-over / mutation algorithms will depend on the problem, and even then, there can be a lot of experimentation involved to get them the best that they can be.

Comment: In genetic algorithms, the mutation is often only half of the problem, the other being the measurment of the "quality" of the solutions. The latter strongly varies between problems.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said the quality of offspring is dependant on a lot of factors and can often require experimentation, using known solutions, to get right.

However, one of the biggest factors in determining the quality of the children is the selection of the parent chromosome. Since stronger parents are more likely to create strong children the type of selection plays a big part.

The best type of selection (more common types are rank based, roulette wheel and tournament selection) like with most things Genetic Algorithms related are largely dependant on the problem, and can often require experimentation to get right.

On whether there is a better crossover/mutation algorithm for the basic Genetic Algorithm the answer is, not really. You can experiment with different kinds of crossover (1-point, two-point, n-point) and mutation (swap or replace). The values for each can also be altered. There are also plenty of things you can change or add to the Genetic Algorithm to improve efficiency (things like culling, duplicate removal, allowing the best chromosome into the next generation) but then your Genetic Algorithm would no longer be a basic Genetic Algorithm. Adding these features also means that you may have to do a lot more experimentation to get the features used, and their parameters, right.

Answer (score 2):

For optimizations problems like the traveling salesperson, you can encode the solution so that all possible crossovers form a valid solution.

For example, instead of treating the genome as a list of cities (and thereby making every genome that misses a city or revisits a city as invalid), you can treat the genome as a list of transformations on a list of cities, starting with some (arbitrary) canonical list of cities.

Suppose we have a list of cities:

1. Azusa
2. Boca Raton
3. Cincinatti
4. Denver

If you treat each pair of bits as an encoding of one of the cities, then only a small number of bit patterns encodes a valid tour.  Mutating and crossing between valid tours has a very small probability of resulting in another valid tour.

If you instead treat every four bits as a swap instruction.  Now any list of bits is valid.  To determine the correct tour, you start with an "official" ordering of the cities, and apply the list of swaps in order.  You'll end with a valid tour, even if some of the swaps are no-ops.

I've used this approach in a couple of optimization problems with good results.

Answer (score 1):

As Michalewicz states in his book, How to solve it, there is no such thing as an off-the-shelf genetic algorithm. So, the answer to your question is basically what @OnABauer stated.

I would only like to complete his answer with a suggestion for you to look into a memetic algorithm ([there is an interesting introduction here](http://sci2s.ugr.es/docencia/metah/bibliografia/MemeticAlgorithms.pdf)). If you add a local optimization operator, chances are that offspring will be improved (beware of local entrapment only).

Answer (score 1):

In essence, genetic algorithm is a type of **search** algorithm.
GA is a particular kind of **heuristic** search.
You are trying to explore the answers which you think are more likely to be the best first.
In GA, the basis of why you choose to explore an answer is because it is **similar** to a previously known good answers (parents).
GA also traditionally can terminate before exploring all the possible answers, which I think is the aspect that worries you the most.

If you want to always look at all possible answer, then you are considering a **exhaustive** search. For example, doing depth-first search through all possible answers.

In conclusion, GA is a heuristic search.
You choose it, if:

1. exhaustive search isn't fast enough.
2. you don't care if the final result is the **best** (globally optimal)
3. you understand how to guess for better answer based on explored answers. This depends on the problem domain. It is what determines what mutation and crossover operators.